# OPAMP remains ON even with no input signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, current-source

I am designing a constant current source using [APEX MP38](https://www.apexanalog.com/resources/products/mp38u.pdf) operational amplifier. The design requires to have a constant current of *+100mA* to be provided for resistive loads from 10Ω to 250Ω (in non inverting mode!)

Here is the typical application provided by the datasheet (in my case I am using it in non-inverting mode):
[image]

So I am basically mis-use the current limiting capability of this amplifier. According to the datasheet the current limiting resistor (R3 = 7Ω in my case) can be calculated:
$$I_{max}={\frac{0.7}{R_{CL}}}={\frac{0.7}{7}}=100mA$$
I have choosen the *Rin=R1=3.2kΩ* and *Rf=R2=27kΩ* which theoretically provides a gain of around *8* times.

The input signal comes from a micro-controller's pin (*high=3.3V* and *low=0V*).
[image]

The opamp is being supplied with +40V and -40V from a bench power supply. The input signal is 0V to 3.3V with period of 4s and 50%.

I have 2 problems:

1. When the load is very small (a brick resistor around 10Ω) the opamp does not turn on! I beleive it tries to turn on but the current limiting circuitry screws up, as you can see from the scope capture (the top waveform is the input signal and the bottom is response of the opamp, in this case it was in inverting mode but it does the same when non-inverting):
   [image]
2. With a higher load (this time 130Ω) The opamp turns on even when there is no input voltage, as soon as I turn on the power supply it outputs around 13.5V which is what it supposed to output, but why when the inputsignal is off (e.g. micro pin is set to low) it does not stop output? I am scratching my head for few days to find the culprit. Please let me know what you thing, what should I check?

Comment: There are some mistakes in your post: Vss/Vdd reversed, feedback should be negative not positive. Please fix those and it will be easier to guess what might be wrong.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany sorry indeed R1 is 3.2k I edidted the text and i'll update the schematic, but it is just for reference only!

Comment: Feedback is pretty important. I assume the supply is actually correct or you would have more smoke etc.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Feedback is on positive, I want it to be non-inverting as I said. Do you think it is the problem!?

Comment: It's **certainly** *a* problem! Even if non-inverting the feedback must be negative (then you apply the input to the non-inverting input). See any tutorial on op-amps.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany oops...then how I am supposed to get +100mA, not -100mA from this opamp? I require it to be positive because of some other chips I am planning to use. P.S. I updated the schematic.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany and sorry to bother, but the first problem with low load (the opamp was in inverting mode just like application in the datasheet) any comment on why it does not turn on and instead does this crazy sinewave thing?

Comment: Even in non-inverting mode the feedback *must* be negative in order to have stable operation. The only difference this makes is that the gain is always greater than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like the below. The gain from the non-inverting input is about 8. With input of 0V the output voltage will try to go to -13.2V and with an input of 3.3V the output voltage will try to go to about +13.2V. If you want double that, reduce R2/R5 to 7/15 each or 3.6K each.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLoaSv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gain of this circuit is 1 + R1/(R2||R5) or

\$ G = 1+ \frac {2 R1}{R2}\$ for R2 == R5

The two resistors bias the amplifier so that you get balanced positive and negative voltages for inputs of 0V/3.3V. Ideally you would get 0V out if V1 = 3.3V/2.

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick, since I did not need the negative output I just connected the Vss to GND and put input signal directly on the non inverting input of the opamp. works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

> why when the inputsignal is off (e.g. micro pin is set to low) it does
>   not stop output?

The screenshot you show is the OPAMP oscillating due to positive feedback. This happens in any linear feedback system (many textbooks on the subject) whether or not there is an input.